# multiple query assign to gridview control in asp.net c# using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

through this code i get error "Input array is longer than number of column in this table"

```
DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
var qry = from c in db.Categories where c.SubCategoryName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) select c;
foreach (var k in qry)
{
      var qry1 = from c in db.ProductMasters where c.ProductNameID == k.CategoryID
                  select new { ProductID = c.ProductID, 
                               TagID = c.TagID, 
                               ProductNameID = (from d in db.Categories 
                                                where d.CategoryID == c.ProductNameID 
                                                select d.SubCategoryName).FirstOrDefault(),
                               CategoryID = (from d in db.Categories 
                                                 where d.CategoryID == c.CategoryID 
                                                 select d.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault(), 
                               ProductType = c.ProductType, 
                               Maker = c.Maker, 
                               Model = c.Model, 
                               SerialNo = c.SerialNo, 
                               MACAddress = c.MACAddress, 
                               Warranty = c.Warranty, 
                               Price = c.Price, 
                               ProductOrderNo = c.ProductOrderNo, 
                               VendorID = (from d in db.Vendors 
                                           where d.VendorID == c.VendorID 
                                           select d.VendorName).FirstOrDefault(), 
                               PurchaseDate = c.PurchaseDate.ToString().Substring(0, 10), 
                               ProductStatus = c.ProductStatus, 
                               Remark = c.Remark };
     dtMain.Rows.Add(qry1);

 }

gridProduct.DataSource = dtMain;
gridProduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: That's not how datatables work.  Consider using a `BindingList<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data table works on Rows and columns concept.  you need to mention all the column name first. add rows to the datatable like this.

```
DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();


for (int i = 0; i < rows .Count(); i++)
            {

                DataRow datarowObj= dtMain .NewRow();
                datarowObj["A"] = yourValue;
                datarowObj["B"] = yourValue;
                datarowObj["C"] = yourValue;
                dtMain .Rows.Add(datarowObj);
            }
```

alternatively as SLAKS mentioned about bindingList. you can use. BindingList

```
return new BindingList<YourClass>(qry1.ToList())
```